# How to enumerate all possible k-connected-components partition of a two dimensional 4-connected grid

Tags: co.combinatorics

Hi all:

Sorry for my bad wordy title, my question is:

Input:

Given a m*n 4-connected grid of points each of which is labelled with an integer $\in\{1,...,k\}$.
We say a label configuration z is feasible (k-connected-components partition) if points of the same label are connected on the grid and there are k different labels in total.

Output:

How many different feasible configuration are there?

Thanks for your help

E.E.

Answer (score 1):

Constraining m=n and k=2, this is http://oeis.org/A068416.